# Build every Microsoft Visual C# 2012 file in separate .dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm making mods for some game that are created through C# .dll files. I started a C# .dll project in my Microsoft Visual C# 2012. However, I want to make several .dll files - specifically one per .cs file.

How would I do that? I want to avoid making too many projects while every project contains just one file.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Having every file be a separate DLL is  overkill.

Comment: I agree with Jared, there's really no good way to do this. Maybe if you tell us what your end goal is, we can be of more help.

Comment: There is actually no sense in it as the dll overhead is hugh. THat will be a mess in memory.

Comment: Well, I'm actually trying to treat every file as a single project. The `dll` mods are small but standalone - so every mod must be in one `dll`. And since the source is short, every mod is one `.cs` file.

Comment: My problem is that I can't compile different projects from one window.

Comment: @TomášZato I don't get it. Can't you make a Visual Studio Solution, with several projects in it? (one per DLL)

Comment: I guess I don't know how. I never saw any difference between Solution and Project to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

What purpose of this? To easily decompile and replace some class? I don't see any profit from this.

Use .cs-files and dynamic (re-)compilation and (re-)loading when needed. Several projects do this. It's quite comfortable way. But not troubleless...

Or make some API that will define what MOD must do and what MOD can do. Most projects that use mod's do this.

Comment: My main problem is that Visual C# only allows one project per window. It's super annoying to have so many windows open, one for every `.dll`